# Get value from other table if condition is not met

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm writing an SQL query:

```
DECLARE @ResidentID AS INT = NULL
DECLARE @Category AS INT = NULL
DECLARE @ResidentStatus AS INT = NULL
DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME = NULL--'2018-02-27'

SELECT DISTINCT r.Firstname, r.Lastname, r.Active FROM Register.Resident r
LEFT JOIN Register.MonitoringStatusOfUser msu ON msu.ResidentID = r.ID
WHERE (r.ID = @ResidentID OR @ResidentID IS NULL)
```

Each resident from Register.Resident 'r' has a field called 'Status' which is an integer. In table Register.MonitoringStatusOfUser I have records of statuses for each user, sort of like a history of status changes. What I want to do is: check if there is a record for a user in Register.MonitoringStatusOfUser '**msu**'. If @Date is between msu.DateFrom and msu.DateTo, then display msu.Status. If not, then display r.Status.

I've already made a left join for Register.MonitoringStatusOfUser. However, I can't figure out how to display r.Status if the @Date condition I've explained above isn't met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the `DISTINCT` is needed.  Add it back in if you need it.

You can put the date condition in the `ON` clause.  Then use `COALESCE()` to get the status you want:

```
SELECT r.Firstname, r.Lastname, r.Active,
       COALESCE(msu.status, r.status) as status
FROM Register.Resident r LEFT JOIN
     Register.MonitoringStatusOfUser msu
     ON msu.ResidentID = r.ID AND
        @Date BETWEEN msu.DateFrom AND msu.DateTo
WHERE (r.ID = @ResidentID OR @ResidentID IS NULL)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. However, I only need to display one status - if the condition for @Date is met, then show the status from Register.MonitoringStatusOfUser. If not, then show the status from Register.Resident.

Comment: im so sorry, I've misread the code! Thank you so much, it works.